# JavaFX WebView: Transparent WebView keeps old content drawn

Tags: java, javafx, webview

The JavaFX WebView can be made transparent through reflection. This allows the WebView to act as an html overlay.

Unfortunately, there is an issue when displaying new content in the WebView. The old content remains drawn, and the new content is drawn on top of the old.

The behavior is not present in Java 10, it started in Java 11 and is still present in JavaFX 15.

Here is an example, where clicking on the black text loads new content into the WebView:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        new WebPage(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class WebPage{
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        public WebPage(Stage mainstage) {
            Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
            scene.setFill(null);

            mainstage.setScene(scene);
            mainstage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

            webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(this::changed);
            webEngine.loadContent("<body style='background : rgba(0,0,0,0);font-size: 70px;text-align:center;'>Fixed Number: 1</body>");

            // Click to display old content on top of the old
            scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
                webEngine.loadContent("<body style='background : rgba(0,0,0,0);font-size: 70px;text-align:center;'>Random Number: " + Math.random() + "</body>");
            });
        }
        private void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                makeWebEngineTransparent(webEngine);
            }
        }
    }

    /** Makes the webEngine transparent through reflection. */
    private void makeWebEngineTransparent(WebEngine webEngine) {
        try {
            Field f = webEngine.getClass().getDeclaredField("page");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Object page = f.get(webEngine);
            Method m = page.getClass().getMethod("setBackgroundColor", int.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(page, (new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)).getRGB());
        } catch ( ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Picture: [image]

Is there a way to avoid the old content staying after loading new content?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to simply use the WebView nearly transparent instead of a fully transparent.

In the code above, replace `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)` with say `new Color(0, 0, 0, 1)`. This will cause the old content to be erased.

The alpha of 1 will make the background nearly impossible to see.

Comment: Thank. It helped me. I have a transparent site with buttons that only had text. When you hover over the buttons, they turned black (this should not be so). new Color (0, 0, 0, 1) solved the problem and made everything transparent. JDK 15, JavaFX15.